# Layouts used by code generated with Data Binding incorrectly reported as UnusedResource by lint

Tags: android, lint, android-databinding

**Lint** is considering layouts used by classes generated with **Data Binding** as unused, therefore triggering the corresponding **UnusedResource** warning.

For example:

***../../src/main/res/layout/activity_start.xml:2: The resource R.layout.activity_start appears to be unused***

despite there's a reference in one of the classes generated with Data Binding:

```
public static ActivityStartBinding inflate(android.view.LayoutInflater inflater, android.databinding.DataBindingComponent bindingComponent) {
    return bind(inflater.inflate(com.tuenti.messenger.R.layout.activity_start, null, false), bindingComponent);
}
```

Is there a way to make lint consider those generated classes in order to avoid these false positives?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've been looking into this and found a solution which allows for the use of generated classes.

First, you must add **checkGeneratedSources = true** to your **lintOptions** block.  For example, inside your app module **build.gradle**:

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        checkDependencies = true
        checkGeneratedSources = true
    }
}
```

Lint should now include the generated source files and will no longer give false positives.  You may run into additional issues where the generated files throw different errors, in my case some of the generated files related to Room were violating the **RestrictedApi** rule.  If that's the case, simply add a rule to the **lint.xml** to exclude that rule from running on the generated code like so:

```
<issue id="RestrictedApi" severity="error">
    <ignore path="build" />
</issue>
```

Comment: checkGeneratedSources = true resolved it for me.
This should be the correct answer.

Comment: Will all databinding layouts be considered to be in use in that way? These files will always be referenced by XXXBinding files.

Comment: @hqzxzwb Data binding layouts are generated code, so yes.

Comment: @jbutton  To add a rule to lint.xml, is it as simple as finding the xml file in the module folder and then edit the file by adding the <issue/> you show above?

Comment: Not working in Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 2

Comment: After applying `checkGeneratedSources` I've received bunch of RestrictedApi lint issues from Room DAOs, so it's not the best solution

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and worked around it by using the `DataBindingUtil` helper instead of the generated class. You can use it that way:

```
binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.activity_start, container, false)
```

Note that it will return a `ActivityStartBinding` and not a generic object, which is exactly what you want. And as your layout is used directly from your code and not from generated code, there's no issue with Lint anymore.

Answer (score -1):

Nope you cannot force the lint to consider the generated classes.I would suggest you to set them to information or ignore instead of warning.

You can definitely set them to Information or Ignore instead of Warning (Window/Preferences/Android/Lint ErrorChecking/Performance/UnusedResources).